# How Type inference work in presence of Functional Dependencies

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, type-inference, functional-dependencies

Consider the code below :

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses,FlexibleInstances,FunctionalDependencies,UndecidableInstances,FlexibleContexts  #-}
class Foo a c | a -> c
instance Foo Int Float 
f :: (Foo Int a) => Int -> a 
f = undefined
```

Now when I see the inferred type of f in ghci

```
> :t f
> f :: Int -> Float
```

Now If I add the following code

```
g :: Int -> Float 
g = undefined 

h :: (Foo Int a) => Int -> a 
h = g
```

I get the error

```
Could not deduce (a ~ Float)
```

I am not able to understand what has happened here? The restriction `Foo Int a` should have restricted the type of `h` to `Int -> Float` as shown in the inferred type of `f`.

Is it because type unification is occurring before resolving the instances ?

[Update]

An explanation given by Dan Doel on the cafe mailing list

> The answer, I believe, is that the difference between the fundep
>   implementation and type families is local constraint information.
>   Fundeps do no local propagation.
>
> So in your first definition, you've locally provided '`Int -> a`', which
>   is acceptable to GHC. Then it figures out externally to the function
>   that '`(Foo Int a) => Int -> a`' is actually `Int -> Float`.
>
> In the second definition, you're trying to give '`Int -> Float`', but
>   GHC only knows locally that you need to provide '`Int -> a`' with a
>   constraint '`Foo Int a`' which it *won't* use to determine that `a ~
>   Float`.
>
> This is not inherent to fundeps. One could make a version of fundeps
>   that has the local constraint rules (easily so by translating to the
>   new type families stuff). But, the difference is also the reason that
>   overlapping instances are supported for fundeps and not type families.
>   But I won't get into that right now.

I still don't understand what that mean. So still looking for better understandable answer.

Comment: I think this is indeed a bit strange. I'd report it as a bug.

Comment: @kosmikus See the explanation given by Dan Doel. I still don't understand what he meant.

Comment: Yes, what Dan says is matching my expectations. Still, even if this is (for the moment) desired behaviour, it's misleading that GHCi auto-improves the type to one that isn't treated as equivalent.

Comment: I thought that misleading and unexpected, yet technically desired, behavior was the *entire purpose* of fundeps! Go figure...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid this problem, you can use type families instead:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, FlexibleContexts #-}

class Fooo a where
  type Out a :: *

instance Fooo Int where
  type Out Int = Float
  
ff :: (Foo Int) => Int -> (Out Int)
ff = undefined

gg :: Int -> Float
gg= undefined

hh :: (Foo Int) => Int -> (Out Int)
hh = gg
```

Type families are nice. Use type families when you can!

---

I'm guessing your error is because ghc can deduce `f :: Int -> Float` from `f :: Foo Int a => Int -> a` and your class definition and instances, but it can't deduce `g :: Foo Int a => Int -> a` from `g:: Int -> Float`.

It's convenient to think of constraints as a secret dictionary parameter on the function. There's an inherent but constrained polymorphism in f that there isn't in g.

I think it's helpful to note that ghci is giving us essentially exactly the same error message as if we tried to define

```
j :: Int -> Float
j = undefined

k :: Eq a => Int -> a
k = j
```

It's obvious that this shouldn't work, because we know that `k` should be contrainedly polymorphic in its second argument. ghc tries to match the type `Int -> a` with `Int -> Float` and fails, complaining that it can't infer `a ~ Float` from the context `Eq a`, even though there's an instance `Eq Float`. In your example, it says it can't infer `a ~ Float` from the context `Foo Int a` even though there's an instance for `Foo Int Float`. I realise *we* can deduce that there's only one possible type for `a`, but by making the class and instance for Foo, you have defined a relation and asserted it's a functional dependency. This isn't the same as defining the function (which is why type families solves the problem - it defines the function).

ghc also complains when you write

```
aconst :: (Foo Int a) => a
aconst = 0.0
```

or even

```
anotherconst :: (Foo Int a) => a
anotherconst = 0.0::Float
```

always because it can't match the constrainedly *polymorphic* `a` it wanted with the specific type you gave it (`Fractional a` or `Float`).

You want

```
forall a.Foo Int a
```

to be the same type as `Float`, but it isn't. There's only one type that satisfies `forall a.Foo Int a`, it's `Float`, so ghci can take `f::forall a.(Foo Int a)=>a->Float` and deduce (using a dictionary for Foo) that `f::Int->Float` , but you're expecting ghci to take `Float` and find notice it's `forall a.Foo Int a`, but there's no dictionary for Float, it's a type, not a type class. ghci can do it one way, but not the other.

Dan's point about local information is that ghc would have to use both `Foo`'s definition and the instance you made to deduce that `Float` can be rewritten `forall a.(Foo Int a)`, and that at this point in compilation, ghc isn't using global information because it's just trying to do a match. My point is that `Float` matches `forall a.(Foo Int a)` but `forall a.(Foo Int a)` doesn't match `Float`, in the sense that `"this"` matches the pattern `(x:xs)` but `(x:xs)` doesn't match the pattern `"this"`.

Comment: I don't think that is the problem. Try giving type `g:: Int -> a` and then see the type of h. I think the answer is somewhat similar to what Dan suggests. I knew the solution using type-families. But the problem is unexpected behavior of FD's.

Comment: I guess my main point I wanted to get across in my answer is that functional dependencies are full of unexpected behaviour, and type families are not, and I still think that's worth recording next to your question.

Comment: Yes, in both cases (your original f and g when `g::Int->a`), ghc is fine to take a constraint and an instance and calculate a type - it deduces `h::Int->Float` from the constraint on h and the instance, but it's having trouble taking a type and matching it to your constraint. In each case ghc can specialise `(Foo Int a)` to `Float` happily, but it's having touble generalising `Float` to `(Foo Int a)`; you're asking it to use the Foo instance backwards on to the way it used it to specialise.